# One of my methods in my Python linked list is returning the error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'"

Tags: python, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to teach myself Python by going back and doing a bunch of data structures. I'm pretty confused why I am getting this error:

File "linkedlist.py", line 60, in get_index
    cur = cur.next
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'

All of my other methods use a similar method. In C++ I'd use pointers for this, but with Python I'm not sure why this isn't working. Everything looks good to me.

Here is my code:

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        # data stored 
        self.data=data
        self.next=None

class linked_list:
    # constructor
    def __init__(self):
        # head node
        # doesn't contain any data; used as placeholder to point to 1st element in the list
        self.head = node()

    # append to end of the linked list
    def append(self, data):
        new_node = node(data)
        cur = self.head

        while cur.next != None:
            cur = cur.next
        cur.next = new_node

    #get the length of the list
    def length(self):

        length = 0
        cur = self.head

        while cur.next != None:
            length += 1 
            cur = cur.next

        return length


    # print contents of list
    def display(self):  
        # array of what is stored in "data" in each node
        data_array = []
        cur = self.head

        while cur.next != None:
            cur = cur.next
            data_array.append(cur.data)
        print data_array

    # get index i in the linked list
    def get_index(self, index):
        # check if index is larger than the linked list
        if index >= self.length():
            print("ERROR: Index passed in is out of range.")
            return None

        # index of i set to 0
        i = 0
        cur = self.head
        # find the desired index and data located there
        while True:
            cur = cur.next
            if i == index: 
                return cur.data
                i+=1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just solved my own question. The i+=1 is indented too far and in the if loop. Also, my issue was in the get_index method. Sorry my question was formatted poorly.

Comment: A linked list is pretty much redundant in python the built-in list type will do almost everything you need, why are you trying to implement one?

Comment: @IainShelvington How is it redundant?  Python has built-in support for arrays (which it calls lists), but not linked lists.  There are many algorithms that are better suited to linked lists.  Your comment is basically saying that linked lists are redundant in any language that has arrays, which clearly isn't true.

Comment: Happy to be proved wrong. A list in python is not the same as an array

Comment: @IainShelvington Lists in Python are implemented as arrays, using the standard computer science meaning of array, i.e. a contiguous block of storage that holds each element in sequence.  I'm not using it in the sense of the Python numeric `array` package.  You're right that the `list` and `array` types in Python are different, but that isn't what I meant.

Comment: I'm aware of the implementation, I am yet to find a use case for linked lists in python

Comment: @IainShelvington Which means you have yet to find a use case for linked lists in any language that supports arrays.  Take a course in data structures.  There are many uses for linked lists.  Here's an obvious one:  Doing an in-place merge sort.  This is natural for linked lists, but for arrays (or Python lists), intermediate storage is required.

Comment: https://www.pythoncentral.io/merge-sort-implementation-guide/ - https://gist.github.com/m00nlight/a076d3995406ca92acd6

Comment: @IainShelvington Did you look at the code?  It uses intermediate copies at each level of recursion.  Do you understand that `lefthalf = alist[:mid]` and `righthalf = alist[mid:]` are copying the entire list, as two halves?  One more time:  Linked lists allow in-place merge sort with no intermediate storage.  Arrays, including Python lists, do not.

Comment: @IainShelvington I think the mistake you're making is that you're confusing convenience with desirability.  Since Python automatically resizes its arrays (lists) as needed, much of the overhead of the arrays is hidden from the user.  But it is still there.  Sure, you can do most things with arrays that you can do with linked lists, but with the overhead of having to reallocate, and copy, the array contents when you resize it.  Linked lists avoid this overhead.

Comment: I did take a course in data structures and algorithms and as such I would not recommend using python for anything that had any strict performance requirements. You are correct, the data structures you describe are far more suitable to an array of problems. In the context of this question, the improvements you describe are overshadowed by overhead of the CPython's interpreter doing it's thing, especially since the question is still using basic python types. You're right though, I shouldn't have said what I said

Comment: @IainShelvington I fully agree with that.  Linked lists don't arise often in Python for 2 reasons:  (1) Python arrays (lists) are very convenient, and hide the allocation logic and overhead, and (2) Squeezing out the last bit of performance isn't an issue in Python, since if performance were that important, you wouldn't be using it in the first place.

Comment: @TomKarzes Which is why I've never found a reason to implement a linked list in python. I'm being argumentative but you get my point

Comment: @IainShelvington Well in all honesty, I have rarely used singly linked lists in Python myself, for those same reasons.  I would be more likely to use them in non-linear context, where the pointers refer to a parent node for instance, resulting in a tree.  I am also more likely to use a doubly-linked list.  While singly-linked lists naturally support a stack, with constant-time push and pop, a doubly-linked list supports queues, and allows for constant-time insertion and deletion at any point in the list, which an array can't do.

Comment: The python data structure that has functionality closest to that is [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque)

Comment: But as you say, python is not the tool for any algorithmic work

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes, dequeues are naturally supported by doubly-linked lists, although doubly-linked lists can insert or remove arbitrary list elements in constant time, which dequeus are not necessarily able to do (depending on the implementation).  I'm not sure what representation the Python dequeue class from the collections package uses.  I suspect they're built out of lists, which are allowed to wrap (hence the size limits), but I could be wrong.

Comment: Seems that deques in python are implemented as doubly linked lists https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/762f93ff2efd6b7ef0177cad57939c0ab2002eac/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#L33

Comment: @IainShelvington To really take advantage of the full power of doubly-linked lists, you either have to use internal links, or else store the external list cells in your data structure so that you can refer to specific points in the DLL for insertion or deletion.  Otherwise you won't be able to take advantage of constant time insertion/deletion or arbitrary elements.

Comment: @IainShelvington Oh, interesting.  Unfortunately, they don't seem to provide a way to reference a specific point in the DLL, so there's no constant-time insertion or deletion of elements (except at the head and tail).  I would prefer if they defined a DLL element class, with value, prev, and next fields.  Then you could suport delete_self, insert_before, and insert_after.

Comment: I'm sure the core developers wouldn't mind if you contributed :)